# SQL SELECT two specific names from table not working

Tags: mysql, sql

| Name | UID | Late |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tin | ABC | 0 |
| Bob | ABC | 0 |

```
SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE Name='Tin' AND Name='Feryal'
```

This query returns nothing for me and only works when I want one name.
I could use the SELECT * but for this case I would like to call specific names in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use In clause.

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE Name IN ('Tin', 'Feryal');
```

You can also use or clause

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE Name='Tin' OR Name='Feryal'
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Amit Verma's answer.

```
 SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE Name='Tin' AND Name='Feryal'
```

Reading that SQL statement out loud, it sounds like this:

I want to select all the rows from logs where the name is equal to Tin AND the name is equal to Feryal.

You can quickly see from that statement, the reason why 0 rows are returned, it's because that is impossible! You cannot have somebody named both Tin and Feryal at the same time unless they are some bizarre super-positional being and the datatype in the table somehow allows for that.

Amit covers the rest.